# Java - How can I avoid using try catch statements

Tags: java, try-catch

I would like to know how I can avoid try-catch statements. Right now I have a Database handler and every time I run a command I have to surround it in a try block like so:

```
try {
    while(levelData.next()) {
        if(levelData.getInt("level") == nextLevel) return levelData.getInt("exp");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can I make it so the actual function throws the exception or something? Rather than having to manually put all these try's in? Its mostly just an aesthetic problem as these try blocks look ugly.

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen if you get an SQLException?

Comment: You can't, really, you can re-throw the exception, but at some point, someone really should handle it (and yes, Java has a default handler, but you should be doing your own laundry!). *"Can I make it so the actual function throws the exception or something?"* ... `public void someMethod() throws SQLException`....You might want to take a look at [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: As a side note, why aren't you using WHERE clauses?

Comment: I think `levelData` is a `ResultSet`, don't forget a `finally` block to `close()` it (or use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)).

Comment: put it in a method and call the method, atleast the try catch wont be littered everywhere.. This assumes that the sql is the same and any responses to exceptions are the same

Comment: @immibis I am, my query isnt shown here.

Comment: @KyleJensen then why are you doing the whole while/if thing instead of adding `WHERE level == <nextLevel>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now I have a Database handler and **every time I run a command I
>   have to surround it in a try block** like so...

I think other answers fail to address the above problems. When I started programming with Java, I hated it when my program was filled with `try`-`catch` blocks for SQL query statements.

The way I work around it is to use a DAO-level-layer to handle the exceptions. For example, If my program need to access a User table, I create a UserDAO class. Then the queries are created and exceptions are caught in that DAO class.

Every time an exception occurs, I do the logging needed and throw a custom-specified [Unchecked Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), e.g. *DatabaseErrorException*. The main difference between an unchecked exception and a checked exception (like `SQLException`) is that you aren't forced to `catch` or `throw` it, so it will not fill your code with the `throws` statement.

*(Yes, you can use throws to avoid using `try`-`catch`, but you must handle it somewhere anyway, and think about your functions having `throws` everywhere.)*

Then we can have a global filter at the highest level of the application to catch all these exceptions which propagate through the program. Usually a database error can't be recovered from, so here we only need to display the error to the users.

Comment: Thank you! Very thorough answer! This was exactly what I needed to do

Comment: @KyleJensen: you are welcome :) If you are interested in learning more about Exception handling, I would recommend reading Clean Code http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882 , it's a classic book which discuss various interesting pragmatic topics (and luckily, very easy to read)

Answer (score 7):

You can throw an exception instead:

```
public void myMethod() throws SQLException {
     while(levelData.next()) {
        if(levelData.getInt("level") == nextLevel)
           return levelData.getInt("exp");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rephrase it: The above code does not throw the SQLException, but it may throw. In Java you have to declare the possible exceptions of your function or you have to catch them inside the function by your own

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method throw an exception with the `throws` keyword, rather than using a `try`- `catch` block, but at some point the exception needs to be handled. What I have found most annoying is multiple `catch` statements, but if you use JDK >= 1.7 they have a multi-catch option available. For exception logging you can use the log4j library.